# Eclipse-How to implement Eclipse workbench actions through plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an IDE Remote for Eclipse where users can forward commands to Eclipse as HTTP requests through a web browser and controls Eclipse accordingly. For example if you type http://localhost/openfile then the Open File window should open. I have already handled the requests. But how do I carry out the respective action?

Say I want to open the New file/project window when the request http://localhost/new is received? How do I do it through my plugin? Which plugin extension should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by 'save open project'? Eclipse doesn't have the concept of saving a project.

Comment: What I meant was saving all files in the currently open project which haven't been saved already. But it could be anything else. If the user types   http://localhost/openfile it should open the Open File window. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to this, what you need to do will vary enormously depending on the action.

To open the New Wizard you can use the existing command `org.eclipse.ui.newWizard` using something like:

```
IHandlerService handlerService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);

String commandId = IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_NEW;

handlerService.executeCommand(commandId, event);
```

Comment: Thanks greg! But how do i get the event parameter? I'm not clicking a button or anything. It's executed entirely from code.

Comment: Often Event can be null, or you can create one yourself with `new Event()`. Some commands may expect a sensible event, others don't care.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got that working! But now the New window is opening multiple times! About 10 New windows open one on top of the other. Maybe its because the trigger function is getting called multiple times. Is there anyway to check whether that window is open already and not open it if so?

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to check this.

Comment: Thanks anyway greg! You saved the day! :)